# Convert currency to to a simple string of numbers

Tags: ms-access, currency

I am attempting in a MS Access query to convert currency to a number string.  For example $1,348.5588 to 134855.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Set the _Format_ property of the currency column/field to: Standard

Answer (score 0):

Well, that currency formatting is only for display - the column is a number.

But, you can say do this in the query:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, HotelTax, 
CStr([HotelTax]) AS HotelTaxS, Description
FROM tblHotelsA
```

So, the query when run gives this:

[image]

## Edit: User wants the number scaled by 100 - no decimal point.

Ok, then use this for the expression in the query:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, HotelTax, 
CStr(format([HotelTax] * 100,"0")) AS HotelTaxS, Description
FROM tblHotelsA
```

And, we get this:

[image]

Comment: The issue is it still leaves the decimal in the numbers.   In your example $5.00 = 5 I would need it to read 500 without impact the other entries.

Comment: see my edit - I have a 2nd example - it should work for you.